# Include list in Python request data

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, python-requests, url-encoding

I'm using the Requests library to `PUT` data to the [Pipeline Deals API](https://www.pipelinedeals.com/api/docs/resources/custom_fields), and the data requires that I PUT a list for a value in the request `data`.

Their example: `"custom_label_83": [ 28, 29 ]`.

This is how I'm `PUT`ting the data:

```
requests.put("https://www.pipelinedeals.com/...", data={'custom_label_83': [28,29]})
```

The issue seems to be that when I `PUT` that example, I end up with only `29` being `PUT`, because the body of the request (after being encoded) is like this:

```
custom_label_83%5D=28&custom_fields%5D%5Bcustom_label_83%5D=29
```

As a result, the field is set twice, with the final result being `29`, instead of a list that includes both `28` and `29`. I would like the body of the `PUT` request to be something like this:

```
custom_label_83%5D=28,29
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour you are experiencing (multiple GET parameters) is the default `requests` behaviour when you pass a list as a value for a key in the `params` dict.

If you would like the output to be `custom_label_83%5D=28,29`, you have to join the list's values:

```
>>> ','.join(map(str, [28, 29]))
'28,29'
```

Comment: Thanks! This did exactly what I was looking for. For some reason, the API still isn't working here, but this code fits the requirement.

Comment: Turns out that (at least for Pipeline Deals), this was the correct syntax: `data = {'some_custom_label[]': 'some value'}`. The `[]` at the end of the label indicates that it's an array.

Comment: @br1ckb0t glad you've got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 28 and 29 to be together, you'll have to combine them within the required list somehow. You could use a string, nested list, nested tuple etc...

```
"custom_label_83": [ '28,29' ] #string example

"custom_label_83": [ [28,29] ] #nested list example

"custom_label_83": [ (28,29) ] #nested tuple example
```